# Using SQL database in Shiny to display a table from the database

Tags: sql, r, shiny

here is the link of data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpHF9ocQpT83RHttxIYz5mzfXqShLtKK/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to make a shiny app that pulls some database and displays it. I have the database file in my workspace and this code works perfectly fine in the console. But when I try to run this in a shiny app it does not work.

```
db<- dbConnect(SQLite(),dbname='pisa_math.db')
      res<-dbGetQuery(db,"select * from dxResponses")
      res
```

When I use the same code above in a shiny app it fails :

```
 library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      tableOutput("tb4")
    )
    
  server <- function(input, output) { 
    output$tb4 <- renderTable(
        
          db<- dbConnect(SQLite(),dbname='pisa_math.db'),
          res<-dbGetQuery(db,"select * from dxResponses"),
          dbDisconnect(db),
          
          res
        )
    }
```

I get the error which says:

> Warning: Error in : external pointer is not valid
> 61: 
> Error : external pointer is not valid

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Warning: Error in : external pointer is not valid
  61: <Anonymous>
Error : external pointer is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error likely does not relate to your database but how you call `renderTable`. As [docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/renderTable.html) indicate, the first argument must be an expression that returns a single R object. By passing comma separated values, you are attempting to use other positional arguments of `renderTable`.

For multiple line expression use curly braces to encapsulate the expression:

```r
server <- function(input, output) { 
    output$tb4 <- renderTable({
        db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname='pisa_math.db')
        res <- dbGetQuery(db, "select * from dxResponses")
        dbDisconnect(db)
          
        res      
    })
}
```

Better yet, handle all processing before `renderTable`:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
    db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname='pisa_math.db')
    res <- dbGetQuery(db, "select * from dxResponses")
    dbDisconnect(db)
 
    output$tb4 <- renderTable(res)
}
```